# Observer back button click from a certain page (Reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is their any way we can observer back button click in react ?

Actually, i have added a code on category page, the functionality it provides is to remain the user anchored on page.

For example : customer browse category page scroll through products & click product page then click **back button** then user see exactly the same category page products which user clicked (i.e same product position).

For this i set below code on category page

CategoryPage.js

```
const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = React.useState('');

 React.useEffect(() => {
   var pathName = document.location.pathname.substr(1);
   if (window) {
     window.onscroll = function (e) {
       setScrollPosition(window.scrollY);
       if(scrollPosition != 0){
         sessionStorage.setItem("scrollPosition_"+pathName, scrollPosition);
       }
     };
   }
 }, [scrollPosition]);

 React.useEffect(() => {
   var pathName = document.location.pathname.substr(1);
   if (window && sessionStorage.getItem("scrollPosition_"+pathName)) {
     $(window).scrollTop(sessionStorage.getItem('scrollPosition_'+ pathName));
     console.log('position_set to = ' + sessionStorage.getItem('scrollPosition_'+ pathName));
   }
 }, []);
```

As you can see code `scrollTop` the screen with value saved in session storage
It works but i need this thing to work only when this scenario
**(i.e user visit category page, scroll through page, click product, product page opens & click back button)**

It should not work with any other scenario like **(user visit category page, scroll through page, click product, product page opens, user click another page or homepage & visit Same category page & with above code it scrolls it to the same page's position)**.

**Solution : Check the previous route is  product page then scroll top else do nothing**

is their any fix for this ?
how to check the previous route is  product page ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: one thing you can try is you can check where the user is coming from . For example if his previous route is your product page then you can do the scroll top else do nothing .

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Shyam,
yes this can be done & it should work also.
Also its ok to save as many sessions if user visits a category page to another category page ?

Comment: Is their any way to  check where the user is coming from 
from product page or homepage in website ?

Answer (score 1):

We can observe a back button click, by listening to the history object. Try the below example,

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const Test = () => {

  const history = useHistory();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (history.action === "POP") {
        
      }
    };
  }, [history])
}
```

event `POP` would mean, back button click.

Ref:- https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history

You could get to know the previous page through location history

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const Test = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    return history.listen(location => {
      if (history.action === 'POP') {
        
      }
    })
  }, [])
}
```

`location.from` will give you the previous route.

**Update in response to comments:**

I see you're using `next/router` which has `beforePopState` for this, it takes a callback and if that cb returns false, then router will not do anything for the `POP` event.

Ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerbeforepopstate

Keep the route history i.e, [pathname or asPath](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-object) in a global state and thereby you could find out if the previous route was product page and on back button click (beforePopState) you could execute your code.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, let me check with this.
How you know its "POP" for back button click ?
Also i need to execute code only when previous route is the product page

Comment: how can i integrate above code with the helpful code you've mentioned ?

Comment: Thanks.
Though i can see error Module not found: Can't resolve 'history' Is their any way it can be done without adding new dependency ? that would be nice

Comment: you should already be having `react-router-dom` ryt? import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'; and then const history = useHistory();. How do you handle routing in your app?

Comment: No i am not have react-router-dom.

Comment: Thanks can you please update the code to make it work with current code which i have added in question ?

Comment: Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: it is difficult to propose a solution without knowing your project structure, used modules, imports, etc. Consider adding a codesandbox with a reproducible code to see the issue and fix. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse, let me add full code

Comment: I need to what code to add in which component,
for example where i need to use beforePopState ?
on category page or productpage ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236444/discussion-between-devhs-and-deechris27).

Comment: sorry, not available for chat. Go to codesandbox and reproduce your issue with the project code required, I'll take a look in my free time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't observe what a user is doing in the browser app itself (i.e. clicking the back button), but you can listen for "popstate" events. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#examples In React you can use [history](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history).

I think you'll find instantiating a `history` object and using it to listen will be easier for you.

[history](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/v4/docs/GettingStarted.md)

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

const useBackListener = (callback) => {
  const listener = (location, action) => {
    if (action === "POP") {
      // back navigation
      callback(location, action);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const unlisten = history.listen(listener);
    return unlisten;
  }, []);

  return path;
};
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, how can i integrate above code with the helpful code you've mentioned ?

Comment: @devhs You pass a callback in, when a back navigation is done the callback is called with the `location` object and `action`. You can check the location.

Comment: Helpful thanks let me check with the code.

Comment: Module not found: Can't resolve 'history'
Is their any way it can be done without adding new dependency ?
that would be nice

Comment: @devhs What I've done in the past is to store a history "stack" in redux of all the routes hit, so if I needed to compare two history entries to see where a user might've navigated from I could do this.